# Postfix deliver mail to correct mail server based on MX Records

Tags: email, debian, postfix, mx-record

We are using `Debian` and `postfix` to send mail for our CMS. Our website and email use the same domain but our email is hosted elsewhere. So, sadly when our server tries to send some mail (from some contact us forms) to user@ourdomain.com it gets rejected because it doesn't realize that it should send the mail to the correct server based on the MX records.

We are using linode.com. Should I update the MX records there? Or should I be doing something in the postfix configuration to let it know about the mail server?

Config:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = caaschool.org, li457-219.members.linode.com, localhost.members.linode.com, localhost
myhostname = li457-219.members.linode.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = 
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Doing an MX record lookup it shows `334006397.mail.outlook.com` for the hostname. I have never had anything to do with the mail for this domain.

Comment: it would be helpful if you provided the relevant postfix logs. Postfix configuration (obtained with postconf) might also be helpul

Comment: I can't imagine the default configuration sending the mail to anywhere BUT the `MX` record.  Are the `MX` records valid (the response is an `A` record and not a `CNAME` record?)

Comment: Wow, the postconf is huge. You sure there are not some relevant lines I can post?

Comment: postconf -n shows only the things you changed

Comment: The MX records are no configured on our server at all.

Comment: Just added the conf items that I have changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the domain in question caaschool.org ?
In that case: Your domain is listed in mydestination, so postfix considers it a local domain and does not send to the mx records.
Remove the domain from mydestination.

Comment: Yes it is. So will it do an MX record lookup somehow? I have not configured any MX records in linode for this domain.

Comment: yes it should. your mx records are configured at worldnic, you don't need to configure them on linode.